# SQL to select products sold in a given year

Tags: sql

Let's say I have a Sales table, that contains columns ProductID, Date, ... some other data. If I want to find how many products were sold in a given year, what query would I use?

I had something like:

```
SELECT YEAR(Date) AS Year, COUNT(ProductID) FROM Sales GROUP BY Year ORDER BY Year;
```

but that isn't correct. Essentially I want a resultset like this:

```
| Year | ProductsSold
| 2000 | 57306
| 2001 | 39683
| 2002 | 30693
| 2003 | 63966
```

I know I need a GROUP BY but I just can't think of how to get this right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer shows keywords escaped using SQL Server syntax, since you used a keyword for your column name and alias.

You probably meant to group by the `YEAR` function applied to the `Date` column (i.e., `YEAR([Date])`) rather than its `Year` alias:

```
SELECT YEAR([Date]) AS [Year], COUNT(ProductID) AS ProductsSold
FROM Sales 
GROUP BY YEAR([Date]) 
ORDER BY [Year];
```

The reason why you can't use the `Year` alias is the order in which a `SELECT` statement is evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

Although I like Sam and Michael's answers,

```
SELECT YEAR([Date]) AS [Year], COUNT(ProductID) AS ProductsSold
FROM Sales 
GROUP BY YEAR([Date]) 
ORDER BY [Year];
```

I would like to add a small modification, I would recommend using

```
SELECT YEAR([Date]) AS [Year], COUNT(DISTINCT ProductID) AS ProductsSold
```

In order to get how many "different" products were sold. otherwise, if one product appears multiple times you will be counting it multiple times as well. If you want to do something like that, you probably have a Quantity column and maybe

```
SELECT YEAR([Date]) AS [Year], SUM(Quantity) AS ProductsSold
```

or something like that would be better.

Comment: Although uniqueness wasn't specified in the problem definition, you certainly pointed out an interesting dilema, so I'm throwing a +1 your way.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT YEAR(Date) AS Year, COUNT(ProductID) FROM Sales GROUP BY YEAR(Date) ORDER BY Year;